# Curl fails to send FCM message

Tags: php, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push notification to my android application using **Firebase**. I have tried it on my local system and it is working fine. this is my code.

```
 function sendPushNotiication($tokens,$message){
    $url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields= array(
        'registration_ids'=>$tokens,
        'data'=>$message
    );
    $headers=array(
        'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
    if($result==FALSE){
        die('curl failed: '. curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I have called this sendPushNotification() method to send the data to firebase. 
Problem is when i put this online on my server. it is giving NULL in $result at var_dump. and after it die with

curl failed.

What is the problem with curl it should be working if it is working on local system.

i have also executed **phpinfo()** and found that

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3
```

Comment: use `===` instead. testing for `== false` is risky, as empty strings, integer `0`, etc... all test as equal to false. `0` is a perfectly valid json response.

Comment: @MarcB thank you for quick response. yes i replaced == with === but if script is working fine on local why it is giving null on server.?

Comment: maybe google's blacklisted your hosting co or something. no idea.

Comment: i don't think so.. because my other sites on same server has curl working.

Comment: Are you able to make other non FCM HTTP requests from your server?

Comment: @ArthurThompson Sry i did not get what you want to say..

Comment: I was asking if it is only FCM curl requests that are failing or is it all curl requests from your server?

Comment: @ArthurThompson NO i have not tried for any other curl request, i am trying it for FCM

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {
            // Set POST variables
        $url = 'Url';

        $fields = array();
        $fields['data'] = $message;
        if(is_array($registration_ids)){
        $fields['registration_ids'] = $registration_ids;
        }else{
        $fields['to'] = $registration_ids;
        }

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}
```

just verify ur code with this.

Comment: i have tried it. it gives same result, NULL. i have also tried by Disabling SSL Certificate support. do we need to add our domain on firebase console..?? i have tried adding domain under Auth that is OAuth redirect domains. but still not working.